# Accumulator not initialized when using reduce.call

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't my accumulator get initialized? I keep getting undefined.

```
var S = "SOSSTSROS";

var radiatedLetters = Array.prototype.reduce.call(S,function(acc,curr){
    if(!curr.match(/[SO]/)){
        acc++;            
    }
},0);
console.log(radiatedLetters);
```

Comment: You need to *return* the accumulator for the next iteration…

Comment: `function(acc, curr) { return acc + !/S|O/.test(curr) }`

Comment: @Bergi this looks good, never used .test before. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [return the accumulated value from the reducer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), not mutate it:

```js
var S = "SOSSTSROS";

var radiatedLetters = Array.prototype.reduce.call(S, function(acc, curr) {
  if (!curr.match(/[SO]/)) {
    return acc + 1;
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, 0);
console.log(radiatedLetters);
```